# How do I dynamically set element name for form validation?

Tags: angularjs

I have a form with input fields generated with an ng-repeat. The field names are set dynamically from the model. I cannot get validation to work. 
Here is the input field that is repeated within ng-repeat:

```
<input class="form-control input" type="number" id="item.id" name="item.name" ng-change="ctrl.updateSub(item)" ng-model="item.qty" max="item.maxqty" min="0">
```

I am trying to validate against the max value, which is also set dynamically.

What I cannot find anywhere is how to set the name within the ng-show classes.

```
<div class="col-sm-2 error" ng-show="form.{{item.name}}.$invalid">
     <small class="error" ng-show="form.{{item.name}}.$error.max">
         You exceeded the maximum allowed
     </small>
</div>
```

How am I supposed to handle the `{{item.name}}` bit? 
Thanks in advance for any help or pointers.
Angular 1.3.12

Answer (score 0):

Firstly `form` is a reserved keyword, you cannot use that as your form name.
Coming to your problem, unfortunately as of right now it is not possible to generate dynamic names for form inputs.

You can achieve what you want with the help of `ng-form`
Have a look at this example :

```
<form name="yourForm" >
  <div ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-form="myInnerForm">
    <input type="text" name="dynamic_input" ng-model="field.name"/>
    <div ng-show="myInnerForm.dynamic_input.$dirty && myInnerForm.dynamic_input.$invalid"> 
      The field is required.
    </div> 
  </div> 
</form>
```